# Using Django's ORM in a Celery Task

Tags: django, django-models, celery, django-celery

How can a Celery task have access to the Django database-abstraction API? Does this need to be coded from scratch using one of the strategies for stand-alone Django ORM usage, or is there a more streamlined, built-in way or common practice?

It seems that nobody is asking this question. However, to me, it's fundamental.

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180843/avoid-recursive-save-when-using-celery-to-update-django-model-fields) implies that it's no big deal, but can someone explain how the session management and ORM scoping works between Celery and Django?

Answer (score 6):

By default Celery pickles its task parameters. Django model instances can be pickled too.

The catch is that pickling a model instance is like taking a snapshot of it *at that time*. Unpickling doesn't touch the database.

Whether this is good or bad depends, I suppose, on your needs. I tend to send a primary key into my tasks and re-query for the object in question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a look at [django-celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery).

When doing work as a celery task, you want to pass all of the details to celery, for example to send an email, you’d pass in values for “from”, “to”, “subject”, and “body”.

If you then wanted to notify the user of the action being completed, you’d probably want to have a look at something like the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) in Django.

I hope that helps.

Comment: django-celery is no longer required. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: @user1252307 is no longer required if you don't wanna access to database.